# TypeError can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python, windows

My program is throwing this error:

```
File "C:\Users\...\Meal Price Calculator.py", 
line 6, in <module> meal = meal * tax 
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by  non-int of type 'str'
```

**Questions:**

- Am I typing the symbols wrong?
- Is it punctuation?

**My code:**

```
meal = input('Enter Amount of Meal ')
tax = input('Enter tax percentage in decimal ')
tip = input('Enter tip percentage in decimal ')
meal = meal * tax
meal = meal / tip
print(meal)
input()
```

Comment: What are the numbers at the end of the lines?

Comment: Please use code formatting, and remove the line numbers. Instead, copy-paste the actual error traceback you get into your question (because Python is usually clearer than stating "there was an error on line 5") .

Comment: Im not sure, they arnt in the real code, so it must be a typo.

Comment: `input()` returns a string, *always* (\*). You'll have to convert it to a floating point or integer yourself, e.g. `tax = float(tax)`, and ditto for `tip`. ((*) in Python 3, that is.)

Comment: the traceback:  File "C:\Users\Aiden M\Desktop\Files\Meal Price Calculator.py", line 6, in <module>
    meal = meal * tax
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: Add your traceback *into your question*. (And change the code to a code block, without line numbers, so that it corresponds to the actual code you're running.)

Comment: Vote to close this as off topic because it doesn't contain a [mcve]. This poster has indicated that it isn't the real code in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070963/my-meal-calculator-has-an-unidentifiable-error#comment83115593_48070963). This site doesn't add *typos*. If you want help explaining why your code isn't working, post your actual code.

Comment: Ok the error is clear, what is your first and second input

Answer (score 2):

The symbols are not wrong.
Is it not punctuation.
It is your variable type that's the problem.
Like what @Evert said, `input()` always returns a string. You have to convert it to a floating point or integer manually.
Since you are asking for the inputs as decimals, you want to use floats.
You code would be like this:

```
meal = float(input('Enter Amount of Meal '))
tax = float(input('Enter tax percentage in decimal '))
tip = float(input('Enter tip percentage in decimal '))
meal = meal * tax
meal = meal / tip
print(meal)
```

*( PS. I don't see the point of an input at the end unless you are double-clicking on the script to run it. I recommend running python scripts from the command line(cmd). Comment if you want help with that. )*

Read more on variables [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_variable_types.htm)

Comment: Meal variable needs to be converted to integer or float as well.